# Angular7 reactiveForm validar campo Email y campos Contraseña + Repetir Contraseña

Tags: formularios, webforms, angular7

Buenas estoy intentando **verificar** el **email** y las **contraseñas** en el nuevo **form reactivo** de **Angular 7** y a parte de las facilidades que me da el nuevo formulario aplicando ciertas **reglas** para la **verificacion** :

```
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre_real:['',Validators.required],
      apellidos : '',
      email :['',Validators.required],
      nombre_usuario : ['',Validators.required],
      password : ['',Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)],
      repetir_password:['',Validators.required, this.compararPasswords],    
      img_perfil:null,
      pais : ['',Validators.required],


    });
```

Quissiera añadir algunas reglas mas, pero **al estilo del nuevo form de angular 7** y pues dice que cree **funciones** y las ponga detras del `Array` de validaciones que tiene cada campo, por ejemplo, creo una **funcion** `validarEmail()` pues me dirijo al `array` de `formGroup` busco el  campo `email` y le añado la **funcion** tal que asi :

```
email:['',Validators.required,this.validarEmail]
```

pero me arroja errores :

```
ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
    at toObservable (forms.js:653)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.asyncValidator (forms.js:641)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:2920)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2893)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControl.setValue (forms.js:3275)
    at updateControl (forms.js:2111)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.js:2096)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.DefaultValueAccessor._handleInput (forms.js:884)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (RegistroComponent.html:60)
```

Simplemente queria hacer dos **comprobaciones** adicionales:

1.Comprobar que haya introducido un **email** valido, es decir, con un `pattern` valido.

2.Comprobar que la **Contraseña** y **Repetir contraseña** sean iguales.

Para estas dos **comprobaciones** he hecho los siguiente:

**Funcion que comprueba email valido**

```
private comprobarEmail(control:AbstractControl){
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    const email = control.get('email');

    let error = null;


    if (re.test(String(email).toLowerCase()) == false) {
      error = {...error, error:'Email no valido'}
    }
    return error;
  }
```

**Funcion que comprueba que las contraseñas sean iguales**

```
  private compararPasswords(control:AbstractControl){
    const password = control.get('password');
    const repetir_password = control.get('repetir_password');

    let error = null;


    //si no coinciden return el error 
    if (password != repetir_password) {
        error = {...error, error:'Las contraseñas no coinciden'}
    }

    return error;

  }
```

Y simplemente, **segun la documentacion** ,añado las **funciones** al **array de reglas** del cmapo que me interese, tal que asi:

```
 nombre_real:['',Validators.required],
  apellidos : '',
  email :['',Validators.required,this.comprobarEmail],
  nombre_usuario : ['',Validators.required],
  password : ['',Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)],
  repetir_password:['',Validators.required, this.compararPasswords],    
  img_perfil:null,
  pais : ['',Validators.required],
```

Pero no da los errores que comente. No se si alguien ha tenido un problema similar. Gracias.

---

**mi buildForm({}) ACTUALIZADO**

```
private buildForm(){
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre_real:['',Validators.required],
      apellidos : '',
      email :['',[Validators.required,this.checkEmail]],
      nombre_usuario : ['',Validators.required],
      password : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
      repetir_password:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8),this.checkPassword]],    
      img_perfil:null,
      pais : ['',Validators.required],


    },
    {
      //validaciones adicionales
      validators: [[this.checkPassword]]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Creo que el error te viene en el `AbstractControl`, el parámetro que recibe ese método es un `FormControl`, prueba hacer el método de `comprobarEmail` así:</strike>

```js
  private comprobarEmail(formControl: FormControl) {
    const email = formControl.value;
    ...
  }
```

**Actualizado**

He estado probando y ya se donde esta el problema, esta en la declaración:

```js
email: ['', Validators.required, this.comprobarEmail]
```

Tiene que estar así:

```js
email: ['', [Validators.required, this.comprobarEmail]]
```

Comment: Realmente la funcion debe recibir un component abstracto.

Comment: En uno de mis proyectos lo tengo como te lo he mostrado, con el `FormControl` y me funciona. Prueba a ver si te funciona así.

Comment: Acabo de probar con el `AbstractControl` y funciona también. Pero `control.get()` me devuelve `null`. Con `control.value` si que me devuelve el valor.

Comment: Y de donde sale ese `this.validatorEmail`

Comment: Ese lo tenia en un proyecto, gasta tu metodo, ya lo he cambiado

Comment: Este error me da ahora : `Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.`

Comment: Has puesto los `Validators` dentro de  los corchetes

Comment: Si, perfecto eso era, se me olvido crear el `Array` de `Array`´s

Comment: en cuanto a la comprobacion de las contraseñas, me sigue dando errores, llevo un rato probando cosas, una cosa que me crea duda es que si antes con el `email` aplicabamos una funcion para un campo en concreto, a la hora de crear una funcion que intervienen dos controles donde deberia de asignar esa funcion? Y como haria esa funcion, porque tal cual la tengo no me esta dando mas que errores

Comment: Voy a subir mir `buildForm({})` actualizado